# Truly limiting folder access

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have broken inheritance to the folder, removed all groups/people and then added a couple specific people to the folder. In advanced permissions it only shows those couple people who can access the folder. But when I do "check permissions" or "manage access" it shows other users are having access because: "Limited Access - Given through the "Style Resource Readers" group". I am one of those users and I can still access this folder even though my name is not listed.

Any ideas on how to truly lock down a SharePoint online folder so only the users listed have the access?

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Go to *Site Settings*
2. Click on the *Site collection features* link
3. and **Enable** the *Limited access user permission lockdown mode* feature

Answer (score 0):

The **Style Resource Readers group** contains a Windows security group named NT Authority/Authenticated Users. This means that all authenticated users can display SharePoint master pages and styles for the pages on your site.

[image]

**Limited Access** is a special system permission which SharePoint provides by default.

So the **Style Resource Readers group** out of the box has the **Read permission to master page gallery**. And, the Style Resource Readers group does not have the Read permission to lists/folders

[image]

[image]